# Precedence and bitmask operations

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

I've come across a (seemingly) very strange case.

Take the number 2 (`0b10`) and bitmask it with 1 (`0b01`)

This should produce `0b00` which is equivalent to 0.

However, here's where Mr Schrödinger comes in:

```
var_dump(0b10 & 0b01); // int(0)
var_dump(0b10 & 0b01 == 0); // int(0)
var_dump(0b10 & 0b01 != 0); // int(0)
```

Whiskey. Tango. Foxtrot.

I am, admittedly, not the sharpest when it comes to bitwise operators - so maybe I've got horribly, horribly wrong somewhere?

However, in Python:

`0b10 & 0b01 == 0` = `True`

`0b10 & 0b01 != 0` = `False`

...so?

Comment: I don't in PHP but in C, C++ you could simply write as `var_dump(!(0b10 & 0b01))`

Comment: Something weirder though: `0b0+1` evaluates to `2` in some versions, due to a parser bug.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You are actually doing this:

```
var_dump(0b10 & (0b01 == 0));
var_dump(0b10 & (0b01 != 0));
```

Try:

```
var_dump((0b10 & 0b01) == 0);
var_dump((0b10 & 0b01) != 0);
```

Comment: Seems to me that PHP has strnage operator precedence overall.

Comment: I guess that's why I **NEVER** rely on precendence in any language. Moreover, I think parentheses make code more readable. In extreme cases you might want to (re-)group and short-comment stuff.

Comment: @AlvinWong You are correct! I think rarely a code need conditional expression like `0b10 & (0b01 == 0)` why would someone apply bitwise with yes no kind of information.

Comment: Well, consider a more common example: the ternary operator, PHP has it backwards, making it different than all other languages. Ref: phpsadness

Comment: Thats why in C and C++ people have warnings for these things.

Comment: @AlvinWong: To be fair, this particular case is equivalent to the precedence in most C-like languages...

Comment: Of course, what else than precedence, programming isn't quantum physics. Still +1 for the obviously correct answer to an awfully overrated question.

Comment: C-like precedence for `&` and `|` is unnatural, and an unfortunate side-effect of C's evolution from 'B'.  See the 'Neonatal C' section of Ritchie's [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html)

Comment: @ChristianRau: It seems the question does show research, is clear, and is useful. What more could you ask for that a lack makes this question overrated?

Comment: I rely on the precedence rules that match what we learned in grade school arithmetic (e.g. multiplication is higher than addition), and a few other common cases. For most expressions more complicated than that I parenthesize liberally.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir The question isn't bad, don't get me wrong, but I still fear most of the up-votes are mainly due to people nerdgasming on the title (which has been changed already, though). But nevermind, it's not that I would care that much (and it may also be such a large number of votes is usual in the PHP area of the site, don't know). And well, what else could have been the problem but precedence, but I don't blame a newbie for not immediately getting that and the question isn't bad.